# How to handle Asynchronous nature of function calls in Java Script

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am creating a function that will return me the result of a DB query. The problem is when I am calling the main function, the query function within the main function(getSessionCode) is not getting executed first.
I tried the Promise manager approach as well as the callbacks but none of those seems to be working.

Code:

```
dbConnectionObject = require('./DatabaseHandler.js');
  dbConnect = dbConnectionObject.getdatabaseConnection();
  var sessioncode;
  function getSessionCode(emailaddress){
      var queryBuild = "select <column name> from <table_name> where email="+ "\'"+ emailaddress +"\'";
      var responseArray;
      dbConnect.query(queryBuild,(err, res) =>{
      if(err)
          {
          console.log(err);
          }
      else if(res){ 
          responseArray=res.rows;`enter code here`
          dbConnect.end();       
          console.log(responseArray);
          return responseArray;
      }  
    });
  }
sessioncode = getSessionCode('gautam.pruthi@abc.com');
console.log(sessioncode);
```

Comment: Expected Result: The 2nd console.log statement(console.log(sessioncode)) should execute at the end. At the moment, the console.log statement within the query function is getting excuted first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Note the above is a server side code in Node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `dbConnect.query()` use callback pattern to handle query result, this callback pattern block you to make query result as your function return value directly.

To resolve such problem, [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) came out to resolve callback pyramid.

1) change `getSessionCode()` to return a Promise 
2) consume Promise eventual value with `then()` or `await` pattern

```
dbConnectionObject = require('./DatabaseHandler.js');
dbConnect = dbConnectionObject.getdatabaseConnection();
var sessioncode;

function getSessionCode(emailaddress) {
    var queryBuild = "select <column name> from <table_name> where email=" + "\'" + emailaddress + "\'";
    var responseArray;

    return new Promise(function(resove, reject){

        dbConnect.query(queryBuild, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);

            } else if (res) {
                responseArray = res.rows;
                `enter code here`
                dbConnect.end();
                console.log(responseArray);

                resove(responseArray);
            }
        });

    });
}

sessioncode = getSessionCode('gautam.pruthi@abc.com');

sessioncode.then((session)=>{
    console.log(session);
})

sessioncode = await getSessionCode('gautam.pruthi@abc.com');
console.log(sessioncode);
```